# NSOutlineView with text-wrapping cells: heigthOfRow

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to implement an `NSOutlineView` with multiple-line cells.

Following advice from this and other sites, I have come up with the following code in the view's delegate.

```
- (CGFloat)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView heightOfRowByItem:(id)item {
    NSTableColumn *column = [outlineView outlineTableColumn];
    NSCell *cell = [column dataCell];

    [cell setStringValue:[item valueForKey:@"label"]];

    return [cell cellSizeForBounds:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, [column width], CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;
}
```

The cell in the outline table column is set to wrap.

I get, however, a strange graphical behavior—the text lines overlap, as seen in http://screencast.com/t/ewJUwRmlGZqh. It seems like the cell is getting the right size, but not pushing down the underlying cells.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure this delegate method is only called when reloading the table cell's data, not during other events like a bounds change.

You'll need to invoke a reload when it's time to adjust row heights, which will cause the table to call this method for each of the visible cells, and consequently perform the resize.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*(This was posted as a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/65669), but should have been an answer of its own. I don't know if it makes sense or not. @asavartsov: feel free to repost this answer as your own, and leave me a comment so I'll delete this copy.)*</sub>

This delegate called whenever someone asked for row height at item. This happen, particularly, in drawing operations which con-sequenced by bounds changing. But, as stated in the documentation,

> `NSTableView` may cache the values this method returns, so if you would like to change a row's height make sure to invalidate the row height by calling `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:`. `NSTableView` automatically invalidates its entire row height cache in `reloadData` and `noteNumberOfRowsChanged`.

You'll need to invoke a `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` or `reload` when it's time to adjust row heights, which will cause the table to call this method for each of the visible cells, and consequently perform the resize.